# Read IBM (AS/400) CDC Journal from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Can I get some guidance on how I could read the CDC journal log on our IBM (AS/400) database. Today we are repliacating the journal events onto a MSSQL database but I would like to look into doing this with C# instead.

Today the CDC journal events stored int MSSQL are later produced onto a kafka topic for other consumers to use, and this could maybe be done faster if the journal are read by the C# application itself than the reading from the MSSQL database.

Comment: Worth making the point that CDC uses the standard IBM i journalling mechanism, not something specific to itself. CDC is pretty well optimised. If you are only using CDC to satisfy the use case you describe, it might be worth making this change, but I wouldn't have thought so otherwise. P.S. I have upvoted this question because I think it's an interesting byway.

Answer (score 2):

There is a system API available, [Retrieve Journal Entries (QjoRetrieveJournalEntries) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/QJORJRNE.htm)

You might find it easier to have a server side program call the above API and send the information to your C# client.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Apache NiFi to reduce the code under management for your end to end flow. 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/113941/change-data-capture-cdc-with-apache-nifi-version-1-1.html

Comment: I think this is for MySQL, how can I read it from nifi and DB AS400 IBM Machine?